# useEffect() never gets called preact

Tags: html, reactjs, local-storage, preact, astrojs

I am using astro and preact. I want this card to render and update its counter every second. Its supposed to show how long you havent smoked. I got a starting Date stored in localstorage. When I try to do this through a js script it seems to work. But when I want to use the useEffect() hook the timer just gets stuck at 0.
[image: the bug]

index.astro

```
---
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
import BaseLayout from '../layouts/BaseLayout.astro';
import FunFact from '../components/FunFact.astro';
import Card from '../components/Card';
import SmokeFreeTimeCard from '../components/SmokeFreeTimeCard';
const pageTitle = "Übersicht";
---
<BaseLayout pageTitle={pageTitle}>

    <Card cardTitle="Funfact" iconClass="fa-regular fa-face-laugh">
        <FunFact />
    </Card>

    <SmokeFreeTimeCard cardTitle="Rauchfreie Zeit" iconClass="fa-solid fa-ban-smoking">
            
    </SmokeFreeTimeCard>

    <Card cardTitle="Finanzen" iconClass="fa-solid fa-money-bill">
        Du hast bereits <b>X€</b> gespart!<br/>
        Dein jähliches Ersparnis beläuft sich auf <b>XXXX€</b>. Das sind <b>XXX€</b> im Monat bzw. <b>XX€</b> am Tag!
    </Card>

    <Card cardTitle="Konsum" iconClass="fa-solid fa-wand-magic-sparkles">
        Du hast bereits <b>XX,XX Zigaretten</b> widerstanden.<br/>
        Auf ein Jahr gerechnet sind das <b>XX.XXX Stück</b>
    </Card>

    <script>
        import "../scripts/index.js";
    </script>
</BaseLayout>
```

Card.jsx

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';

const Card = ({ cardTitle, iconClass, children }) => (
  <div class="card" style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
    <div class="card-header" style={{ color: '#ACEB98' }}>
      <i class={iconClass}></i> <b>{cardTitle}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">
        {children} {/* Hier werden die eingefügten Texte gerendert */}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Card;
```

SmokeFreeTimeCard.jsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'preact/hooks';
import Card from '../components/Card';

const SmokeFreeTimeCard = ({ cardTitle, iconClass }) => {
  const [timeElapsed, setTimeElapsed] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const dateOfReturn = localStorage.getItem('dateOfReturn');
      console.log('Date of Return:', dateOfReturn); // Überprüfe das Datum im localStorage
      if (dateOfReturn) {
        const startDate = new Date(dateOfReturn);
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const elapsedMilliseconds = currentDate - startDate;
        console.log('Elapsed Milliseconds:', elapsedMilliseconds); // Überprüfe die vergangene Zeit
        setTimeElapsed(elapsedMilliseconds);
      }
    }, 1000);
  
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  const formatTime = (milliseconds) => {
    const seconds = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000);
    const hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    const minutes = Math.floor((seconds % 3600) / 60);
    const remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    return `${hours} Stunden ${minutes} Minuten ${remainingSeconds} Sekunden`;
  };

  return (
    <Card cardTitle={cardTitle} iconClass={iconClass}>
        {typeof timeElapsed === 'number' && (
            <>Du bist <b>{formatTime(timeElapsed)}</b> rauchfrei! Weiter so!</>
          )}
    </Card>
  );
};

export default SmokeFreeTimeCard;
```

Comment: Your code seems absulutely fine. The problem might be with your date string in `localstorage`. Can you share the value of `localStorage.getItem('dateOfReturn')`. Also, can you try setting `localStorage.setItem("dateOfReturn", new Date("2/6/2024"))` to ensure the date is stored in correct format.

Comment: @Chinz `localStorage.getItem('dateOfReturn')` returns `"2024-02-26"` how its supposed to be

Comment: Thats really weird. Working fine on my machine.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Nope nothign but I think I might have found out whats wrong. When setting `localStorage.setItem("dateOfReturn", new Date("2/6/2024"))`  `localStorage.getItem('dateOfReturn')` returns this `"Tue Feb 06 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)"`

Comment: or wait no this has nothing to do with it thats how its supposed to be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257094/discussion-between-chinz-and-luke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as far as I researched, I found that any [browser-related APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Introduction) are not accessible in Astro. As Astro components run on the *server*, so we can’t access these browser-specific objects.

The `localStorage` is also a part of `window` which is indeed a browser API. Hence, it will not be accessible by Astro directly.

### Solution:

The solution to fix this is *hydrating* the React/Preact component whereever it is being used. Thus, we need a *client directive* saying when to load it.

For this, you just need to add `client:load` to your component in index.astro:

```js
        <SmokeFreeTimeCard
            cardTitle="Rauchfreie Zeit"
            iconClass="fa-solid fa-ban-smoking"
            client:load
        />
```

**Another solution** could be to use the old-classic `script` as you mentioned as well, mentioned in Astro documentation as:

> If the code is in an Astro component, move it to a  tag outside of the frontmatter. This tells Astro to run this code on the client, where document and window are available.

Comment: Oh my, I am so stupid. I literally did that while testing but somehow forgot about it. Thank you very much !

Comment: Haha, Took me some time as well as this is the first time I worked with Astro!